# My production server has bad blocks, now what?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, fsck, ubuntu-14.04, bad-blocks

My server has crashed for Nth time in a couple of months, so I decided to do a `badblocks` test. I have used `fsck` to detect and mark `badblocks`, and it has indeed detected some. If I am correct, this means the filesystem will not use those blocks anymore to store data.

But, what happens to the data which was already there? Has it been moved? It was probably corrupted to begin with, so probably the files which were using those blocks are broken. Now I have several open questions:

1. can I detect which files have been affected?
2. how can I check if those files are corrupted or not after `fsck`?
3. is there any way to tell my distribution (Ubuntu 14.04) to "reinstall all packages, as they are cached in the system"? (that is, no upgrades, just re-installation of the current versions, without overwriting any configuration files)

Note: for completeness I paste here a result of the `fsck`:

```
root@rescue:~# fsck -vcck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
/dev/sda2: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes

Running additional passes to resolve blocks claimed by more than one inode...
Pass 1B: Rescanning for multiply-claimed blocks
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 8: 119060233 119060234 119060592 119060615 119060616 119060617 119060618 119060619 119060620 119060621 119060623 119060624 119060625 119060626 119060632 119060633 119060635 119060636 119060637 119060638 119060639 119061755
Pass 1C: Scanning directories for inodes with multiply-claimed blocks
Pass 1D: Reconciling multiply-claimed blocks
(There are 0 inodes containing multiply-claimed blocks.)

File <The journal inode> (inode #8, mod time Mon May  5 14:17:18 2014) 
  has 22 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 1 file(s):
        <The bad blocks inode> (inode #1, mod time Thu Aug  7 19:11:37 2014)
Clone multiply-claimed blocks<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060233 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060234 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060592 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060615 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060616 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060617 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060618 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060619 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060620 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060621 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060623 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060624 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060625 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060626 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060632 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060633 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060635 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060636 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060637 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060638 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119060639 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Error reading block 119061755 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read).  Ignore error<y>? yes
Force rewrite<y>? yes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (23499, counted=23477).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #2016 (23956, counted=23961).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #3633 (65514, counted=0).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong (231534163, counted=231534168).
Fix<y>? yes

/dev/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

      154609 inodes used (0.26%, out of 59736064)
          47 non-contiguous files (0.0%)
           9 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 154209/10
     7404456 blocks used (3.10%, out of 238938624)
          99 bad blocks
           2 large files

      126167 regular files
       27996 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
           0 links
         437 symbolic links (382 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
------------
      154600 files
```

Comment: What's wrong with your hardware? Can you fix that?

Comment: No, it is a dedicated host, low priceplan, no support, discontinued. They won't even answer emails (ovh)

Comment: Now's a good time to move to a reliable provider...

Comment: agree, if your own hardware, look at replacing disk, if host is remote, and they will not answer then change provider.

Comment: Well maybe you should move to another server, then. That's not so hard to do at all.

Comment: No time for that :( Now that the blocks are marked as `badblocks`, can't I assume that the disk will work (for a while at least) more reliably?

Comment: @MarcStürmer: look for a new provider, backup, reconfigure new server, transfer data, get all my applications, ssh keys, etc. I am looking at a one-week task at least. Not to speak about lost contract (I have paid for one year hosting). Besides, my current provider is quite cheap with high bandwidth and very big disk.

Comment: One week? My own server is being hosted at OVH as well (though I guess I am running a much bigger machine than you do) and I already switched there machines twice. I had the old and new machine running up for a certain time slot in parallel, and transferring all stuff took me less than one day.

Answer (score 2):

First, take a look at the Bad Block HOWTO for smartmontools:

https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto

Second, if you don't already have it, time to implement a working backup strategy.

If you need a certain availability of your server, you might also want to consider implementing a RAID-1, mirroring.

And either way it's time to get rid of the old hard disk drive and get a new one. It failed you already enough times in the past, so it is quite certain this is not going to be better in the near future and beyond.

Comment: Agreed, backup what you have to do and get rid of this ailing beastie.

Comment: Link is broken.